# How can i create multiple command of size N?

Tags: c++

If i was given a size n and i want to create a command of p1 to pn. They all do the same thing, but access different queue. I got the queue part down, but i can't seem to figure a way to make this accept p and a number. Is there any other way i can do this?

i have tried a for loop and while loop it doesn't work out well, because it keeps crashing

```
for(int i = 0; i < n; i++
{
     if(command == 'p' && i)
     {
           //store something in queue[i]... i already did this part
     }
}

//what i want is but just in 1 command looping... so the last line (if(command == 'p' && n))
if(command == 'p' && 1)
if(command == 'p' && 2)
// all the way to n
if(command == 'p' && n)
```

Comment: `'p' && i` That is not a string concatenation.

Comment: BTW, `&&` is *logical* AND.  Also, a non-zero integer will evaluate to *true*.

Comment: yeah i know it is the reason why my thing is crashing. that why im trying to find a new way to rewrite this

Comment: To concatenate numbers to strings see `std::ostringstream` and `snprintf`.

Comment: If command is a string, parse it extracting the number, then use a std::vector (or array) or switch on the number. Perhaps better, make command a class with a char and an int member.